# How do I designate arguments in a nested map?

Tags: function-construction

Say I have two lists,

```
list1 = {a, b, c}
list2 = {x, y, z}
```

and I want to map a function f over them to produce

```
{f[a,x], f[a,y], f[a,z], f[b,x], f[b,y], f[b,z], f[c,x], f[c,y], f[c,d]}
```

I would assume I map the function over the first list to produce a "list of functions", which then run over the 2nd list, something like:

```
Map[Map[f[#1, #2]&,list1]&, list2]
```

but I can't figure out how to leave #2 "empty" until the 2nd map kicks in. How can I separate them to generate all combinations of arguments?

Comment: _I can't figure out how to leave #2 "empty"_: You might be able to get away with `Function` — `Map[Function[x, Map[f[#1, x] &, list1]], list2]` — although I'd use `Outer` myself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What you try to achieve here is called [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) which can be used in other languages like Haskell naturally. In *Mathematica* this does not work like that.

But what about

```
Outer[f, list1, list2]
(*
  {{f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z]}, 
   {f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z]}, 
   {f[c, x], f[c, y], f[c, z]}}
*)
```

or `Flatten@Outer[f, list1, list2]` if you want a flat list?

Of course this did not answer your question. Therefore, the real answer is: you can separate the `Slot`s by using `Function` explicitely:

```
Map[Function[p2, Map[Function[p1, f[p1, p2]], list1]], list2]
(*
  {{f[a, x], f[b, x], f[c, x]}, 
   {f[a, y], f[b, y], f[c, y]}, 
   {f[a, z], f[b, z], f[c, z]}}
*)
```

Here, it is clear that the `p1` parameter is for the inner `Function`, while `p2` is for the outer one. But note, that for your ordering, you need to do switch parameters.

Comment: Perfect! Learned a lot, and solved the problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

`Distribute` is also handy.

Assuming `f` is not `Listable`:

```
In[39]:= Distribute[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}], List]

Out[39]= {f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z], f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z], 
 f[c, x], f[c, y], f[c, z]}
```

Comment: This outputs `{{f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]}}`. `Apply[f,Distribute[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}, List],1]` gives the result above

Comment: I do get the right result with the input `Distribute[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}], List]`

Comment: Yes you are right, probably I had earlier applied some rules that affected the result. I cannot reproduce them - I will try on my other machine also tomorrow. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Not at all. But interesting, I wonder what setting would give you that result.

Comment: I found the usual suspect. I had set f's Attributes to Listable. So maybe this should be noticed...

Comment: I think it is worth to be noticed too. Nice find!

Answer (score 6):

Or you could use `Tuples`, which appears a bit more natural to me.

```
Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
```

creates

```
{{a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c, z}}
```

Afterwards `Apply` can be used to apply your function to the sublist

```
Apply[f , Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}], {1}]
```

creates:

```
{f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z], f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z], f[c, x], f[c, y], f[c, z]}
```

### Addition: comparison of speed:

create some random data:

```
list1 = RandomReal[1, 10^3];
list2 = RandomReal[1, 10^3];
```

Usage of a pure function to summarize the arguments `(#1 + #2) &`

```
 Apply[(#1 + #2) &, Tuples[{list1, list2}], {1}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

yields `{0.944316, Null}`

```
Outer[(#1 + #2) &, list1, list2]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

yields `{0.506706, Null}`

---

Comment: I didn't know about tuples, but I had come to the same sort of solution (lists as arguments) using shifts and transposes. Apply[f, <list things>, 1] worked great to turn the lists into actual arguments. Thanks!

Comment: `Apply` (@@@) would be a better choice here than `Map`

Comment: Of course Mike is right: `Apply` is what you were looking for. I missed to notice that you explicitly not wanted to end up with a list of variables as input argument.