# Chained sums with Nest

Tags: summation, functional-style

I'm looking to calculate a chained sum like this
$$
 C_m = \sum\limits_{i_1=1}^N
 \;\sum\limits_{i_2=i_1+1}^N
 \;\sum\limits_{i_3=i_2+1}^N
 \cdots
 \;\sum\limits_{i_m=i_{m-1}+1}^N
 A_{i_1}A_{i_2}A_{i_3}\cdots A_{i_m}
$$
For example, when $m=3$, this becomes
$$
C_3 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N
 \;\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^N
 \;\sum\limits_{k=j+1}^N
 A_i A_j A_k
$$
Of course the point is I want $m$ to remain unspecified in the algorithm. Now, I know how to implement this by manually making the iterator lists (e.g. with `Tuples`) and applying `Sum` on it. But to me that feels more like a hack than elegant code.

As I always try to get my code as elegant as possible, I see this as a good opportunity to learn.One of the concepts I always have difficult to grasp (but would love to master), is the use of `Nest` and `Fold`. A this sum can be seen as a function nesting on itself
$$
 C_m = \sum\limits_{i_1=1}^N A_{i_1} \left[
 \;\sum\limits_{i_2=i_1+1}^N A_{i_2} \left[
 \;\sum\limits_{i_3=i_2+1}^N A_{i_3} \left[
 \cdots\vphantom{\sum\limits_{i_3=i_2+1}^N}
\right]\right]\right]
$$
I'd expect `Nest` to be an ideal candidate. I've tried a bit, but the best I could come up with is

```
f[g_,j_] := Sum[g[k]A[k], {k,j+1,n}]
F[x_] := f[x,#]&

c[m_] := f[Nest[F,1&,m-1],0]
```

I find this particularly ugly, especially the two function definitions that still need a pure function inside `F`, as well as the fact that I need to wrap an additional `f` around `Nest`. It gets even uglier if I try to avoid the need to define `f` and `F`:

```
c[m_] := Sum[
  Nest[ Function[var,Sum[var[k]A[k],{k,#+1,5}]&], 1&, m-1][l] A[l]
, {l,1,n}]
```

with the need to use `Function` and `&`.

So here's my question: is there a neater way to achieve this chained sum using `Nest`? If not, maybe by using `Fold` or another functional construct?

Comment: One can extend each sum to run from 1 to `n` by using `UnitStep[i[2]-i[1],i[3]-i[2],...]`.

Comment: @yarchik but the question is specifically on how to do this with `Nest`. Using `UnitStep` would depend on minimally two iterators each and hence can't be nested

Comment: I really wouldn't use `Nest[]` for this application, mostly because it is more efficient to have `Sum[expr, r1, r2, ...]` rather than the nested `Sum[expr1 Sum[expr2 Sum[...], r2], r1]`.

Answer (score 3):

`Table` does this automatically.  You should be able to adapt the following code:

```
f[m_, n_] := Sum[
   Product[A[i[j]], {j, 1, m}] // Evaluate, 
   Sequence @@ Prepend[Table[{i[j], i[j - 1] + 1, n}, {j, 2, m}], {i[1], 1, n}] // Evaluate
  ]
```

Thus

```
f[2, 3]
(* A[1] A[2] + A[1] A[3] + A[2] A[3] *)
```

and

```
f[3, 5]
(* A[1] A[2] A[3] + A[1] A[2] A[4] + A[1] A[3] A[4] + A[2] A[3] A[4] + A[1] A[2] A[5] + A[1] A[3] A[5] + A[2] A[3] A[5] + A[1] A[4] A[5] + A[2] A[4] A[5] + A[3] A[4] A[5] *)
```

---

Alternatively, generate the indices directly, and apply the function to them, like so:

```
f2[n_, m_] := Times @@@ Map[A, Subsets[Range[m], {n}], {2}] // Total
f2[3, 5]
(* A[1] A[2] A[3] + A[1] A[2] A[4] + A[1] A[3] A[4] + A[2] A[3] A[4] + A[1] A[2] A[5] + A[1] A[3] A[5] + A[2] A[3] A[5] + A[1] A[4] A[5] + A[2] A[4] A[5] + A[3] A[4] A[5] *)
```

and

```
f[3, 5] - f2[3, 5]
(* 0 *)
```

Or

```
f3[n_, m_] := Sum[Times @@ A /@ is, {is, Subsets[Range[m], {n}]}]
```

Comment: As I specified in the original question, I know how to implement this by manually making the iterator lists (though I have to admit your solution with `Map` and `Subsets` is pretty neat). The question is how to do this with `Nest`, because I want to learn to use the latter more and this seems like a perfect use case..

Answer (score 0):

["Nest[f,expr,n]
gives an expression with f applied n times to expr."](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html)

`Nest` takes
a function,
an expression,
an n of positive Integers.

No more, no less.

`Nest` is somehow outdated.

It is superseded by [`Composition`.](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html)

`Composition` is the mathematical elementary term from with `Nest` is derived.

There is an example in the documentation of Composition for a sum:

```
Composition[HoldForm, Plus] @@ Range[20]
___
\!\(
TagBox[
RowBox[{"1", "+", "2", "+", "3", "+", "4", "+", "5", "+", "6", "+", 
    "7", "+", "8", "+", "9", "+", "10", "+", "11", "+", "12", "+", 
    "13", "+", "14", "+", "15", "+", "16", "+", "17", "+", "18", "+", 
    "19", "+", "20"}],
HoldForm]\)
```

This clears that Sum and Nest are rather different.

`Sum` is derived from `Plus` in the above manner. The documentation page of [`Plus`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plus.html) shows some alternative to `Sum`.

To built up complicated products Mathematica offers the built-in [`Product`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html). There is neither a line with `Nest` on the documentation page of `Product` nor vice versa.

What does that imply for Your question?
Now at first nothing. But it is a strong hint.

While `Nest` is iterative with n, the "times" constant at the third argument position, `Product` does not require a x" but an iterator i with start and end. That is what Your summands represent. I accept the examples in the documentation page for `Product` are far to easy or much the specialized.

There are some nice examples and methods, how to make this more efficient:

```
∑=2coscos′∏=+1sin′

    NSum[Cos[θ[[i]]] Cos[Θp[[i]]] Product[    Sin[θ[[j]]] Sin[θp[[j]]], {j, i + 1, d - 1}], {i, 2,    d - 1}]


f[M_, n_] := Reverse[Table[Cos[θ[i]] Cos[θ'[i]], {i, 2, n}]].PadLeft[FoldList[
Sin[θ[M - #2] θ'[M - #2]] # &, Sin[θ[M] θ'[M]], Range[M - 3]], Max[n - 1, 0], 1]
```

This question is already concerned about [sum or product with exclusions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9288/sum-or-product-with-exclusions).

Sum is more essential for getting closed formulars like in this example:

```
Sum[Product[i^2, {i, 1, n}], {i, 1, n}]
n (n!)^2

n = 4;
Times @@ Flatten@Table[f[a[i] - a[j]], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, i + 1, n}]
```

or

```
With[{n = 6}, Times @@ f /@ Subtract @@@ Subsets[Array[a, n], {2}]]
```

can be either done with an iterator or a list. The iterator needs the coefficients list to be already defined and iterates over it in a linear fashion. In more modern Mathematica versions the second version shall be faster in most contexts.

The formula makes use of different operators `@`, `@@` and `@@@` that are different to `Composition` `@*`.

This is a highly rated answer about [scan vs map vs apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46238/scan-vs-map-vs-apply?noredirect=1&lq=1). This answer explains some differences between [Composition and Apply](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78979/what-is-the-difference-between-composition-and-sequential-applications?noredirect=1&lq=1). This answers go much deeper in the topics related: [v10s operator forms what are they good for?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56504/v10s-operator-forms-what-are-they-good-for?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Some common misconception is addressed in this answers: [how do i designate arguments in a nested map](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15480/how-do-i-designate-arguments-in-a-nested-map).

```
ClearAll[list1, list2, a, b, c, x, y, z, f]
list1 = {a, b, c}
list2 = {x, y, z}
___
Map[Map[f[#1, #2] &, list1] &, list2]
__
list2
___
Map[Function[x, Map[f[#1, x] &, list1]], list2]
___
list2
```

But the desired result is this

```
Outer[f, list1, list2]
(*
  {{f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z]}, 
   {f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z]}, 
   {f[c, x], f[c, y], f[c, z]}}
*)

Map[Function[p2, Map[Function[p1, f[p1, p2]], list1]], list2]
```

(*
{{f[a, x], f[b, x], f[c, x]},
{f[a, y], f[b, y], f[c, y]},
{f[a, z], f[b, z], f[c, z]}}
*)

If f in not listable this can be too written this way:

```
Distribute[f[{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}], List]
(*
  {{f[a, x], f[b, x], f[c, x]}, 
   {f[a, y], f[b, y], f[c, y]}, 
   {f[a, z], f[b, z], f[c, z]}}
*)
```

The next alternative is

Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
(*{{a, x}, {a, y}, {a, z}, {b, x}, {b, y}, {b, z}, {c, x}, {c, y}, {c,
z}}*)

```
Apply[f, Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}], {1}]
```

(*{f[a, x], f[a, y], f[a, z], f[b, x], f[b, y], f[b, z], f[c, x],
f[c, y], f[c, z]}*)

And this, in turn, allows for the desired `Nest`:

Nest[f, #, 1] & /@ Tuples[{{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}}]
(*{f[{a, x}], f[{a, y}], f[{a, z}], f[{b, x}], f[{b, y}], f[{b, z}],
f[{c, x}], f[{c, y}], f[{c, z}]}*)

This question about [nest-fold-is-there-an-extension-for-more-than-2-arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39476/nest-fold-is-there-an-extension-for-more-than-2-arguments) refers to a chapter [5.5.3  Restriction of Fold-ed function to two arguments is spurious](http://www.mathprogramming-intro.org/book/node236.html) of an online book by Leonid Shifrin and an example with three slots:

```
multiFoldList[f_, start_, args__List] := 
 FoldList[f @@ Prepend[#2, #] &, start, {args}\[Transpose]] 
____
multiFoldList[#1 (1 + #2) - #3 &, 1000, {.01, .02, .03}, {100, 200, 
  300}]
___
{1000, 910., 728.2, 450.046}
```

These are very special but these make the trick and the extensions are already included.

For now finally, I like to refer to this overview article

[alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica/](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7924/alternatives-to-procedural-loops-and-iterating-over-lists-in-mathematica/7925#7925)

that includes some examples using Fold and Nest and compare this in different situations to alternative built-ins. This is all quite nice and offers deeper knowledge into what `Nest` does and can do and what not. I compare the built-in `Nest` to other built-ins and combinations and `Composition`s.

Search the Mathematica documentation for Iterator to get this as the better definition for the input value n and some explanation for the Mathematica paradigm selection about that.

There are two definitions for Expression in the Mathematica documentation one for the cells and one for the Wolfram Language interpreter. So such a search guide into inputs dedicated for the helpfulness of WolframAlpha

Have a look at [FixedPoint](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPoint.html) a built-in historically grouped with Nest and for the generation of Mathematica users as the limiting built-in of Nest for infinite iterations, applications. The famous tutorial was Applying functions repeatedly.

[image: Wolfram Language iterator notation] defines the ranges for the indices that can Mathematica based on the Wolfram Language cope with.

So that is what Nest and alike is lacking and Prodcut has.

Comment: "`Nest` is somehow outdated." - this is manifestly false.